# failed to lock variable during move and rename of files in SSIS

Tags: ssis

Newbie question. I believe this is one of the most common errors. I found several of them on msdn forum itself but probably there are many ways on achieving this error? Please help.

I am trying to move and rename some images from one folder to another (and yes I have seen the blog by Rafael Salas and many others but none of them helps).

Like moving from \server1\images\123-456.jpg to \server2\images\123456.jpg

I am using a foreach.

Source variable is built dynamically. In the first iteration @imagePath = \server1\images\123-456.jpg ( i checked using messagebox.show)

I have defined @remoteImagePath = \server2\images\ (which never changes) and @revisedImageName = 123456.jpg (built dynamically in script task using string replace - also checked using messagebox.show)

In FileSystem Task, I am using  SourceVariable as @imagePath and using Expressions to define Destination as in @[User::remoteImagePath] + "\" +  @[User::revisedImageName]

Dont know for what reason, I am getting this error

Failed to lock variable "\server2\images\123456.jpg" for read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created.".

Comment: A screenshot of your package control flow would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Set the IsSourcePathVariable to True and set the SourceVariable to a SINGLE variable.
If you use the expression editor to set Source using multiple variables, or anything else apart from a SINGLE variable it will not work. If you want to concatenate hard-coded strings to variables, or multiple variables, do this by creating a new variable in the package, and use the Expressions tab in the variables tab to build the variable as a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe expressions editor needs syntax

```
   @[User::remoteImagePath] + "\\" + @[User::revisedImageName]
```